# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured. SOS from django beginner

Tags: python, django

I am kind of novice in django and I need your help!!!

my console says

"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import."

But I don't know why...

this is my "boardapp/urls.py"
'''
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

```
urlpattern = [
    path('', main_page, name='main')
]
```

'''

and this is my "awsdjangoproj/urls.py"
'''
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('boardapp/', include("boardapp.urls"))
]
```

'''

Do you guys have any idea how to fix this tiny problem^^;;;

Comment: there is a typo in your file, write urlpatterns on both files

Comment: in your `boardapp/urls.py` it should be `urlpatterns` instead of `urlpattern`

Answer (score 0):

remove the typo in your boardapp/urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', main_page, name='main')
]
```

as a better practice instead importing * import the file name specifically

```
 from .views import main_page
```